# Tor for modules over categories

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

$\newcommand\Vect{\mathrm{Vect}}\newcommand\Hom{\mathrm{Hom}}$Let $A$ be a (small, whatever else we need) $k$-linear category for a field $k$. Let $M$ be an $A$-module, i.e., a functor $M\colon A \to \Vect$, and $N$ be an $A^\text{op}$-module. $AWe can form the tensor product

$$M \otimes_A N = \int^{a \in A} Ma \otimes_k Na,$$

which lies in $\Vect$. This should be enough to define $\mathrm{Tor}^A_i(M, N)$ by the long exact sequence. I have questions about this functor:

- Is it balanced? I assume yes. Does this already follow from the Embedding Theorem and balancedness for modules?
- Is it computable in terms of free modules? What is a free module, even? I know about the free-forgetful adjunction, but is there a more hands-on description of free modules? Is $\Hom_A(a,-)$ for $a \in A$ a free module? Are all free modules direct sums of this?
- Are projective modules flat?

I'd guess that all answers to these questions are affirmative. Where can I find more about that?

Comment: Interesting question; I have tried to compute something in this direction years ago, but didn't find anything particularly enlightening. I *think* this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.07086 goes in a similar direction (cf. section 2.2), but I strayed away from homological algebra before having the headspace to understand it. Simone is a dear friend, and a superb mathematician: I'll drop him a line with this post :-)